# iptables --to-port on linux kernel 3.4.103

Tags: linux, redirect, embedded, firewall, iptables

My embedded system is using linux kernel 3.4.

I tried the command to set iptable rule:

`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080`

But I got this message:

```
iptables v1.4.10: unknown option `--to-port'
Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.
```

Isn't it possible to use `--to-port` option on linux kernel 3.4?
Is there any other option or solution?

Answer (score 0):

You must install apckage `iptables-mod-nat-extra` that is `iptables extensions for extra NAT targets. Includes: - REDIRECT`

Take a look [HERE](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/netfilter)